# How to redirect the output of a c code to a text file using another c code

Tags: c, file-io

I have a c code file (let's say A). I wanted to redirect the output of that code to a text file by using another C program (say B). But the thing is I can't touch (edit) the A file. Is there a way to do so by using `FILE` operations, maybe?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. For starters, "C code" does not output anything. Rather, C code can be compiled into a *program* (or *executable*) which may print output to a number of locations including a file or the terminal. Second, why do you need to use yet another C program to redirect output of the first? There are much easier ways to redirect the output of an executable than writing a C program.

Comment: @Daniel would be of more help if you could point out the alternatives as well :)

Comment: Answers will be very platform specfic. One a lot of systems it would be just "a.exe | b.exe ". By the way its a "C program" not a "C code"

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

Probably the easiest, yet least flexible solution would using system function:

```
system("A.exe <someargs> > filename.txt");
```

If you want more flexibility, you should look into your platform APIs. On Windows, you can use CreateProcess specifying a handle to which redirect each of the streams (stdin, stdout and stderr).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: system(), dup2(), popen() won't work. Is there any other way?